# Uncaught TypeError: $.simpleWeather is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, reference

I am trying to implement [simpleWeather.js](http://simpleweatherjs.com/) on my website.

Unfortunately, when I place the html in my website, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: $.simpleWeather is not a function

I am referencing simpleWeather.js at the top of my html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
```

And it gets loaded on website:

[image]

It works perfectly on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/xklfq) though :/ Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

My full code looks like this:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //copied javascript from codepen.io
</script>
<style type="text/css">
   //copied css from codepen.io
</style>
//copied html from codepen.io
```

Comment: Where is your jquery script tag in relation to your simpleweather script tag? (They must be in that order: jQuery first, then simpleweather.)

Comment: I think you are trying to invoke `simpleWeather` before plugin has been loaded...

Comment: `jquery.min.js` reference is just above the `jquery.simpleWeather.min.js`. I did everything as in the codepen.io example :/

Comment: @GintasK: Move the full content of your question **into** the question. External links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Separately: If you were doing everything as in the Codepen, it would be working. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you probably have your scripts in the wrong order. Your `script` tag for jQuery must be **before** your `script` tag for simpleWeather. Then your script *using* simpleWeather must be after that. (If you're using a script loader, you need to ensure that load order.)

Answer (score 0):

Please check order of code...

You have to include library first then you can access that $.simpleWeather() method. code order something like this.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.simpleWeather/3.1.0/jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
...
...
...
<script>
$.simpleWeather({
    zipcode: '76309',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
        html = '<h2>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</h2>';
        html += '<img style="float:left;" width="125px" src="images/weather/'+weather.code+'.png">';
        html += '<p>'+weather.temp+'&deg; '+weather.units.temp+'<br /><span>'+weather.currently+'</span></p>';
        html += '<a href="'+weather.link+'">View Forecast &raquo;</a>';

        $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        $("#weather").html("<p>"+error+"</p>");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // your code
});
```

Also, write the `script` tag after `html` and `css`